# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied installing TensorFlow with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I followed the instruction from TensorFlow's official site:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

But I got this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

'/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/external/__init__.py'
```

After re-insalling anaconda, got a different error

```
Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, numpy, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: setuptools 20.3
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```

Comment: Try conda remove setuptools 20.3 and then continue installation and the permission denied error shows up when you are not the owner of the folder modify the ownership of the anaconda folder and you will be able to proceed with the installation of packages in your anaconda environments

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install  --upgrade --ignore-installed https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

use "--ignore-installed" flag to prevent errors about easy_install.